# How to set width of bar dynamically in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[for one value the bar width is width of canvas so i want only to change the width of bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrG9T.png)

how to fix the width of bar size ?

Comment: Please share your code and don't just post an image

Comment: Stackoverflow really needs to implement something to stop users from posting images with the title "enter image description here".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Check this out](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)

```
barThickness
```

> Manually set width of each bar in pixels. If not set, the base sample
>   widths are calculated automatically so that they take the full
>   available widths without overlap. Then, the bars are sized using
>   barPercentage and categoryPercentage.

Your code should be something like this:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
       scales: {
          xAxes: [{
             barThickness: 10
          }]
    }
});
```

[I made this example for you](https://jsfiddle.net/f6th3g1k/8/)

Comment: var chart2 = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");

window.myBar = new Chart(chart2).Bar(barChartData{
responsive: true,
scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
scaleFontColor: "#c5c7cc",
 
});

Comment: this one is the code where to add option varible please let me know,

Comment: i added the option variable after data but it automatically minimizes the chart .but i want only to reduce the bar thickness

Comment: please help me i tried lot to set width of bar but it is not affecting the chart

Comment: @SpoortiHonnatti I'v made some changes, look at it. Hope this edit help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can set it on the `Chart` object

```
import {Chart} from "chart.js"

Chart.defaults.datasets.bar.barThickness = 73;

//also try barPercentage, maxBarThickness
```